# How to improve the user experience on a user records flow?

Tags: usability, web-app

I'm building a SaaS product and having doubts on how to organise the navigation and interaction in a user records flow.

The flow consists of a stock transaction record and the document objects are supposed to be stored forever.

In my application menu, I have three elements:

- Remove From Stock
- Add To Stock
- Show Stock Transactions

Both `Remove From Stock` and `Add To Stock` will open an input page where the user will select the stock item `article`, `description` and `quantity` and a new record is added to database. `Date/Time` and `type` (added/removed) fields are added automatically. The latest added field is shown in screen after commit.

The `Show Stock Transactions` option will show all of my transactions over time. I've opted to use a date filter instead of pagination, as the following example:

[image]

The user can select a specific date range (Today, Yesteday, etc.) or choose to type specific dates on the FROM and TO inputs.

In practice, this approach is getting "complaints" from the following points:

a) When adding new transactions, I should be switching screens on the menu.
b) Every time I add a new transaction, I have to switch to "Show Stock Transactions" to see the added record. The added record is not easily visible on screen.
c) There is no clone buttons. I need to be able to clone a previous transaction, no matter how old it is.

I kindly ask for suggestions on how to improve the usability of the flow and the navigation.

Comment: Hi Mendes. Can you please show us all the screens that the user is interacting with. Is add a stock a transaction? Why isn't the added record easily visible?

Comment: Add a stock and Remove from stock are all transactions and both are simple input screens.

Comment: Ok. How do these screens show? are they pop-ups on a home/landing page, or are they individual pages that are loaded? Where does the menu sit when switching between screens? And why do you have to switch screens from the menu when adding new transaction, I assume you should be focused on entering the data for the new transaction. Thanks.

Comment: The menu sits in the top header (top menu). The input screens are individual pages.  So to enter some data the user selects the option on the top menu and then an input page appear. When concluding the new added record is shown in screen.

Comment: After adding a new record you are showing the stock transaction page right? That page is the image that you have attached to your post?

Comment: No. I'm showing a detail page for the item.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

HI Mendes, here's what I had in mind.

The default page is the Transaction page. Because this is the most relevant information for the user. You have two buttons: Add to stock and Remove from stock at the bottom of the table.

You don't need to show the detail page for the item after submitting it. You will show the transaction page with the highlighted new entry.

Once you click on the entry or refresh the page the 'new entry' highlight  disappears.

If you wish to see details of the transactions you double click on them and you will show a pop up.

You add an extra row for selecting the entries. If you select an entry then the duplicate entry button shows/activates.

The table entries could be fixed height with a scroll or you could have an infinite scroll with the add remove buttons being sticky.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Hope this helps.